# Why does wp_die() not work when inside a namespace?

Tags: filters, namespace

Consider the following code copied from ACF docs, refactored to work inside a namespace:

```
add_filter('acf/location/rule_match/user', __NAMESPACE__ . '\acf_location_rule_match_user', 10, 4);
function acf_location_rule_match_user($match, $rule, $options, $field_group)
{

    var_dump($options);
    wp_die();

}
```

The problem is, nothing happens. 
I confirmed this only occurs when I'm inside a namespace.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you have added wp_head and wp_footer in header and footer file respectively ?

Comment: yes, i think the problem is when used inside a namespace

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to dump variables you could use error_log($var) or error_log(print_r($var, 1)) for arrays and objects.

Be sure WP_DEBUG_LOG and WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY constants are defined in your wp-config.php file and debug.log file will appear and update in wp-content folder.